# Why i am always getting invalid token?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

Whenever i hit the api with postman i always get invalid token .can anyone help me out? I am trying to fetch all users registered . I copy the token generated and paste it to api but all i get is "message": "Token is invalid !!". please help me out

```
def token_required(f):
@wraps(f)
def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    token = None
    # jwt is passed in the request header
    if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
        token = request.headers['x-access-token']
    # return 401 if token is not passed
    if not token:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing !!'}), 401

    try:
        # decoding the payload to fetch the stored details
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        current_user = User.query\
            .filter_by(public_id=data['public_id'])\
            .first()
    except:
        return jsonify({
            'message': 'Token is invalid !!'
        }), 401
    # returns the current logged in users contex to the routes
    return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)

return decorated
```

to get all the users

```
@app.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def get_all_users(current_user):
    # querying the database
    # for all the entries in it
    users = User.query.all()
    # converting the query objects
    # to list of jsons
    output = []
    for user in users:
        # appending the user data json
        # to the response list
        output.append({
            'public_id': user.public_id,
            'name': user.name,
            'email': user.email
        })

    return jsonify({'users': output})
```

token:
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwdWJsaWNfaWQiOiJmY2Y2OTBmNS0wNGViLTRjYzUtOTQ0ZC01M2ZkMDU4MjMxNTkiLCJleHAiOjE2NTg3NTU2MDV9.oNc7J2oT7ux-t1I-DioA0Lwf22ArWbGxrrkNsmIOZ10"

Comment: Can you pls. add the token to the question? Is it really a JWT? Is the secret stored in the config correct? Doe the token contain a field 'public_id'?

Comment: probably, your code is throwing an exception after the token check. please, use debug and ensure that the token validation part is OK. also, please send a different response in the except, like a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Marco Frag Delle Monache debug is on and its not throwing any error except "message": "Token is invalid !!"

Comment: the token looks fine and contains the public_id. What about the secret?  Do oyu have the correct secret in the config? I think what Marco means is that you can't distinguish if the exception is thrown by jwt.decode or User.query. Step by step execution or additional logging after jwt.decode would help.

Comment: exactly. try using a different response in the second message and see where your program has the error.

Comment: You're getting the error message "Token is invalid !!" because your code uses that as a catchall error if _anything at all goes wrong_.  The actual error might be something else entirely...

Answer (score 0):

Your error caught might be anything. you should not use except without specifying the exception. for the sake of debugging return the error caught in the try-except block. as follows:

```
    try:
        # decoding the payload to fetch the stored details
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        current_user = User.query\
            .filter_by(public_id=data['public_id'])\
            .first()
    except Exception as e:
        # output e
        print(e)
        return jsonify({
            'message': f'Token is invalid !! {e}'
        }), 401
```

Fix the error and change your try-except block to catch specific exceptions.